# Four equations with five unknown and the Wolframalpha can solve them

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

$$a+b+c=1\tag 1$$
$$a*k_1+b*k_2+c=1\tag2$$
$$2a*k_1^2+2b*k_2^2+2c=1\tag3$$
$$3a*k_1^3+3b*k_2^3+3c=1\tag4$$
the Wolframalpha gives the solution as follow:
[image]

**How did this happen?????**

Comment: I do think that you improve readability by omitting the asterisks and writing $a$ times $b$ as $ab$. That’s how mathematical writing usually goes.

Comment: There are more solutions as you given here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what WA is doing, but that's certainly not the only solution.  The general solution can be written as
$$ \eqalign{a&=-\,{\frac {3}{ 2\left( k_{{1}}-1 \right)  \left( 6\,k_{{1
}}-1 \right) }}\cr b &=-\,{\frac {9}{2 \left( 3\,k_{{1}}+2 \right) 
 \left( 6\,k_{{1}}-1 \right) }}\cr c&={\frac {6\,{k_{{1}}}^{2}-2\,k_{
{1}}-1}{2 \left( k_{{1}}-1 \right)  \left( 3\,k_{{1}}+2 \right) }}\cr
k_{{2}}&=-k_{{1}}+\frac13} $$
with $k_1$ arbitrary (but not equal to $1$, $1/6$ or $-2/3$).